# ssh -Q key not listing all key types?

Tags: linux, openssh, ssh-host-key

I am having some problems with understanding which types of host keys my SSH daemon actually provides or supports (stock debian buster, sshd 7.9.p1). From the manual (`man sshd_config`):

> ```
>  HostKeyAlgorithms
>          Specifies the host key algorithms that the server offers.  The default for this option is:
>
>             ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>             ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>             ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>             ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>             rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>             ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>             ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,
>             ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
>
>          The list of available key types may also be obtained using "ssh -Q key".
> ```

Please note the last line. When following the advice given there:

```
root@odysseus /var/log # ssh -Q key
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

I've got two questions:

1. As an example, the man page states that `rsa-sha2-256` is part of the default for `HostKeyAlgorithms`. But this string does not appear in the output of `ssh -Q key`.

   How does this fit together? How can something be a default which even doesn't exist?

   The above example implies that `ssh-rsa` might be insecure, because it doesn't have `sha2` in its name, and thus might be `sha1` or even `md5` based.
2. What does the string `-cert-v01@openssh.com` in some of the algorithm type names mean? Are these the types for certificate-based authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for here with `ssh -Q key` is a listing of all the key types.  With the `rsa-sha2-256` signature algorithm, as well as the obsolete `ssh-rsa` (RSA with SHA-1) algorithm, the key type is still `ssh-rsa`, since both types of signatures use the exact same key.  If you want to know what signature types are available, run `ssh -Q sig` (example from my Debian sid system):

```
$ ssh -Q sig
ssh-ed25519
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
rsa-sha2-256
rsa-sha2-512
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
```

On newer versions of OpenSSH, you also have `ssh -Q HostKeyAlgorithms`, which prints the values that are valid in that option:

```
$ ssh -Q HostKeyAlgorithms
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
rsa-sha2-256
rsa-sha2-512
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

Note that whether your fingerprint is SHA-2 or not has nothing to do with the signature algorithm.  If you generate an RSA key, it can be used for both SHA-1 and SHA-2 signature unless you specify otherwise.  You would typically want to remove `ssh-rsa` from the `HostKeyAlgorithms` option unless you have a compelling reason to use it, or you can just solve the problem entirely by using an Ed25519 key, which always uses a secure algorithm.

The `-cert-v01@openssh.com` type indicates an OpenSSH certificate.  This is useful if you have a controlled environment, like a company, and you want to create a certificate authority to sign OpenSSH keys and restrict access to only those keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for that enlightening answer, accepted and +1. Got it - the man page is misleading then because most people will understand it in the sense I did. Amusingly, I already had tried `-Q HostKeyAlgorithms`, but this only produced an `Unsupported query` error; obviously, OpenSSH in Debian buster is too old. `ssh-rsa` being in that directive is just a leftover from some experiments, it isn't there in my production systems.